# How do I not include rows that have matching values in 2 columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has 3 columns. I do not want to repeat the row based on 2 columns that have the same values.

```
  |start_date(date)| end_date(date) |theDiff(integer)
  ---------------------------------------------------
  |2018-05-14      |  2018-05-18    |        5      |
  |2018-05-14      |  2018-05-18    |        10     |
  ---------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Output:

```
  |start_date(date)| end_date(date) |theDiff(integer)
  ---------------------------------------------------
  |2018-05-14      |  2018-05-18    |        5      |
  ---------------------------------------------------
```

I have many such rows and do not want them to repeat. I just want to add their first occurrence. I always want it to output the lower difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you expect the first occurrence of all different (start_date, end_date).

You can use row_number() function and then select rows where row number = 1.

```
with x as
(
    select start_date, end_date, theDiff,
           row_number() over (partition by start_date, end_date order by start_date) rn
    from   tbl
)
select start_date, end_date, theDiff
from   x
where  rn = 1;
```

> ```
> start_date | end_date   | thediff
> :--------- | :--------- | ------:
> 2018-05-14 | 2018-05-18 |       5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=21ec01413c8db4c3886c77156848ff46)*

You can move CTE to the FROM clause:

```
select start_date, end_date, theDiff
from
    (
        select start_date, end_date, theDiff,
               row_number() over (partition by start_date, end_date order by start_date) rn
        from   tbl
    ) x
where  rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how the resulting theDiff is determined, some alternative `AGGREGATING` functions:

```
-- diff between max and min
SELECT start_date, end_date, MAX(thediff)-MIN(thediff)
FROM T
GROUP BY start_date, end_date

-- min value
SELECT start_date, end_date, MIN(thediff)
FROM T
GROUP BY start_date, end_date
```